# How can I implement bottom tab, drawer and stack navigation with react-native?

Tags: react-native, mobile, navigation, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Basically, what I want do is an App that has the following navigation:
WelcomePage -> Login or Register -> Home (that has the Drawer and the BottomTab)

[here's an image of my prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY1mY.png)

I actually was able to implement the three types of navigation but there's still some problems that I can't solve, like:

- When I am on a page of the BottomTab and try to go to Home using the Drawer it doesn't work
- The names on the header doesn't match the pages

I'm using React Navigation 6

OBS: I honestly just followed some tutorial I found on YT but they didn't have everything I needed. If you know a better way to do all this stuff please tell me :/

What I did to implement the three navigations was:

- Created the page 'AuthNavigator.js' in order to do the Stack Navigation and later called it in on App.js. To  implement the Drawer on the Home page I put it as a component and named it 'Home'

```
// AuthNavigator.js

import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import {Login, Register, Welcome } from "../../pages";
import DrawerNavigator from './DrawerNavigator';


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const AuthNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Welcome"
            component={Welcome}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Register"
            component={Register}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Login"
            component={Login}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={DrawerNavigator}
            options={{headerShown:false}}
          />
      </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default AuthNavigator;
```

```
// App.js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AuthNavigator from './components/navigation/AuthNavigator';

export default function App() {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <AuthNavigator/>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

- For the Drawer I created 'DrawerNavigator.js' and to connect it with the BottomTab I also put it as a Component

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer'

import CustomDrawer from './CustomDrawer'
import { Profile, Chat, Home} from '../../pages'
import BottomTab from "./BottomTab";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function DrawerNavigator(){
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator 
        drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}>
          <Drawer.Screen
            name="Home" 
            component={BottomTab}
          />
          <Drawer.Screen
            name="Profile" 
            component={Profile}
          />
          <Drawer.Screen
            name="Chat" 
            component={Chat}
          />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    )
}

export default DrawerNavigator;
```

- Lastly, the code for the BottomTab:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

import {Pacient, Schedule, Home} from '../../pages'


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function BottomTab(){
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={Home}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Pacient"
                component={Pacient}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Schedule"
                component={Schedule}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}

export default BottomTab;
```

I would really appreciate any help!